# open popup window in web page using javascript on android webView issue

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, webview, popup

I'm developing an application for web page that opens a popup windows inside the web page when we click on an element.

Now the problem is when I click on that element using java script code, the click invokes but there is no popup windows...

the HTML code of the element :

```
<a href="#" id="m_id" target="_blank">
    some codes here...
</a>
```

and I've used these codes in my activity :

```
after defining my webView :

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(client);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.addJavascriptInterface(iface, "droid");

....

to click on the element :

webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('m_id').click();");
```

I should remmember that I know that the click invokes correctly, but no popup window...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to override and implement `WebChromeClient.onCreateWindow()`. Please refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onCreateWindow%28android.webkit.WebView,boolean,boolean,android.os.Message%29) for the API.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, final boolean dialog,
            final boolean userGesture, final Message resultMsg) {
        // Create your sub window here.
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but this didn't help me... :(

+ of this, when I click on that elements menually, the only thing is that the part of the page that the dialog should be shown in, changes to black and nothing loads in...

Comment: Well you need to do a couple of things within `onCreateWindow()`, e.g. creating new WebView, or creating an Android Dialog, etc. and you need to show it by yourself. Because this is the way that **WebView** callbacks to your app to indicate that a pop up window should be opened (triggered by JavaScript).

Comment: thank you for your response, but another problem is that the onCreateWindow() isn't being called for me, at all !!! :/ any opinions ???